# How To Change Firebase BigQuery Integration 'Dataset Time To Live' From 60 Days To Does Not Expire?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

We've recently upgraded our BigQuery integration in Firebase from Sandbox to Blaze, but the 'Dataset Time To Live' is still 60 days. We've updated the dataset's 'Default table expiration' in BigQuery from 60 days to 'Never', but it's still only retaining the last 60 days of data in the historic event table and didn't change the 'Dataset Time To Live' field in Firebase. We've also updated our Data Retention settings in GA4 to retain data for the last 14 months, but it didn't have an effect on the BQ integration table expiration either.

Any help on how to get the 'Dataset Time To Live' to be set to 'Does not expire' would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Once you've updated the dataset's `Default table expiration` all new tables within this dataset will have `Table expiration = Never`, but all already existing tables will still have the old value. You need to [update it manually](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#updating_a_tables_expiration_time) for all existing tables. Also check if there any [partition expiration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#partition-expiration) configured.